# JPEG Streaming Issue- How can I stream the images to a server of my choice?

Tags: c#, motion, mjpeg

To keep the intro short, I will mention that I have been building an application that involves executing remote commands from a private website that I have built and having my personal home computer respond to those commands.

I discovered that live desktop-streaming would be a perfect feature, and I am planning to use an iframe to fit it into my site. However, I cannot seem to find a good C# library which will allow me to stream my desktop in realtime.

Other than this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371955/Motion-JPEG-Streaming-Server

The problem is, that only allows me to stream my desktop to localhost, 127.0.0.1, and the other local host links.

I need a way to modify it to be able to have it stream to a server of my choice, from which I can then access it. For example www.mystream.com/stream.php

It consists of two classes: ImageStreamingServer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

// -------------------------------------------------
// Developed By : Ragheed Al-Tayeb
// e-Mail       : ragheedemail@gmail.com
// Date         : April 2012
// -------------------------------------------------

namespace rtaNetworking.Streaming
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a streaming server that can be used to stream any images source
    /// to any client.
    /// </summary>
    public class ImageStreamingServer:IDisposable
    {

        private List<Socket> _Clients;
        private Thread _Thread;

        public ImageStreamingServer():this(Screen.Snapshots(600,450,true))
        {

        }

        public ImageStreamingServer(IEnumerable<Image> imagesSource)
        {

            _Clients = new List<Socket>();
            _Thread = null;

            this.ImagesSource = imagesSource;
            this.Interval = 50;

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the source of images that will be streamed to the 
        /// any connected client.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<Image> ImagesSource { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the interval in milliseconds (or the delay time) between 
        /// the each image and the other of the stream (the default is . 
        /// </summary>
        public int Interval { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a collection of client sockets.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<Socket> Clients { get { return _Clients; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the status of the server. True means the server is currently 
        /// running and ready to serve any client requests.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsRunning { get { return (_Thread != null && _Thread.IsAlive); } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the server to accepts any new connections on the specified port.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="port"></param>
        public void Start(int port)
        {

            lock (this)
            {
                _Thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ServerThread));
                _Thread.IsBackground = true;
                _Thread.Start(port);
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the server to accepts any new connections on the default port (8080).
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            this.Start(8080);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {

            if (this.IsRunning)
            {
                try
                {
                    _Thread.Join();
                    _Thread.Abort();
                }
                finally
                {

                    lock (_Clients)
                    {

                        foreach (var s in _Clients)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                s.Close();
                            }
                            catch { }
                        }
                        _Clients.Clear();

                    }

                    _Thread = null;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This the main thread of the server that serves all the new 
        /// connections from clients.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="state"></param>
        private void ServerThread(object state)
        {

            try
            {
                Socket Server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                Server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,(int)state));
                Server.Listen(10);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Server started on port {0}.", state));

                foreach (Socket client in Server.IncommingConnectoins())
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ClientThread), client);

            }
            catch { }

            this.Stop();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Each client connection will be served by this thread.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="client"></param>
        private void ClientThread(object client)
        {

            Socket socket = (Socket)client;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("New client from {0}",socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));

            lock (_Clients)
                _Clients.Add(socket);

            try
            {
                using (MjpegWriter wr = new MjpegWriter(new NetworkStream(socket, true)))
                {

                    // Writes the response header to the client.
                    wr.WriteHeader();

                    // Streams the images from the source to the client.
                    foreach (var imgStream in Screen.Streams(this.ImagesSource))
                    {
                        if (this.Interval > 0)
                            Thread.Sleep(this.Interval);

                        wr.Write(imgStream);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                lock (_Clients)
                    _Clients.Remove(socket);
            }
        }


        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Stop();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    static class SocketExtensions
    {

        public static IEnumerable<Socket> IncommingConnectoins(this Socket server)
        {
            while(true)
                yield return server.Accept();
        }

    }


    static class Screen
    {


        public static IEnumerable<Image> Snapshots()
        {
            return Screen.Snapshots(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="delayTime"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IEnumerable<Image> Snapshots(int width,int height,bool showCursor)
        {
            Size size = new Size(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

            Bitmap srcImage = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
            Graphics srcGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(srcImage);

            bool scaled = (width != size.Width || height != size.Height);

            Bitmap dstImage = srcImage;
            Graphics dstGraphics = srcGraphics;

            if(scaled)
            {
                dstImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
                dstGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(dstImage);
            }

            Rectangle src = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
            Rectangle dst = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            Size curSize = new Size(32, 32);

            while (true)
            {
                srcGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, size);

                if (showCursor)
                    Cursors.Default.Draw(srcGraphics,new Rectangle(Cursor.Position,curSize));

                if (scaled)
                    dstGraphics.DrawImage(srcImage, dst, src, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                yield return dstImage;

            }

            srcGraphics.Dispose();
            dstGraphics.Dispose();

            srcImage.Dispose();
            dstImage.Dispose();

            yield break;
        }

        internal static IEnumerable<MemoryStream> Streams(this IEnumerable<Image> source)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            foreach (var img in source)
            {
                ms.SetLength(0);
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                yield return ms;
            }

            ms.Close();
            ms = null;

            yield break;
        }

    }
}
```

MjpegWriter

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

// -------------------------------------------------
// Developed By : Ragheed Al-Tayeb
// e-Mail       : ragheedemail@gmail.com
// Date         : April 2012
// -------------------------------------------------

namespace rtaNetworking.Streaming
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a stream writer that can be used to write images as MJPEG 
    /// or (Motion JPEG) to any stream.
    /// </summary>
    public class MjpegWriter:IDisposable 
    {

        private static byte[] CRLF = new byte[] { 13, 10 };
        private static byte[] EmptyLine = new byte[] { 13, 10, 13, 10};

        private string _Boundary;

        public MjpegWriter(Stream stream)
            : this(stream, "--boundary")
        {

        }

        public MjpegWriter(Stream stream,string boundary)
        {

            this.Stream = stream;
            this.Boundary = boundary;
        }

        public string Boundary { get; private set; }
        public Stream Stream { get; private set; }

        public void WriteHeader()
        {

            Write( 
                    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                    "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=" +
                    this.Boundary +
                    "\r\n"
                 );

            this.Stream.Flush();
       }

        public void Write(Image image)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = BytesOf(image);
            this.Write(ms);
        }

        public void Write(MemoryStream imageStream)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendLine(this.Boundary);
            sb.AppendLine("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
            sb.AppendLine("Content-Length: " + imageStream.Length.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine(); 

            Write(sb.ToString());
            imageStream.WriteTo(this.Stream);
            Write("\r\n");

            this.Stream.Flush();

        }

        private void Write(byte[] data)
        {
            this.Stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        private void Write(string text)
        {
            byte[] data = BytesOf(text);
            this.Stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        private static byte[] BytesOf(string text)
        {
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        }

        private static MemoryStream BytesOf(Image image)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms;
        }

        public string ReadRequest(int length)
        {

            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            int count = this.Stream.Read(data,0,data.Length);

            if (count != 0)
                return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, count);

            return null;
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {

            try
            {

                if (this.Stream != null)
                    this.Stream.Dispose();

            }
            finally
            {
                this.Stream = null;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

This application should work over internet as well. Make sure that the port you access through it remotely is open.

If you don't want to have to open a port for the app to work. then consider changing the source above to make a reverse connection instead , where your desktop computer acts as a client rather than a server.

Good luck